# Where do I find the shutdown reason notes for Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Where can I find the shutdown reason notes for Windows Server 2003?

I sometimes fill these in, but I never see them again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shutdowns events are located in the System Event log (Event 1074).

You can filter for Source: USER32
If your running windows 2003 and specify a reason, it will also be logged in 
the description.
It should look something like this:

Event Type:    Information
Event Source:    USER32
Event Category:    None
Event ID:    1074
Date:        12/14/2005
Time:        1:31:52 PM
User:        
Computer:    
Description:
The process winlogon.exe has initiated the restart of computer 
 on behalf of user  for the following reason: No 
title for this reason could be found
Reason Code: 0x800000ff
Shutdown Type: restart
Comment:

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Event Viewer?

Comment: I just did and I see nothing.  More to the precisely, I see 1000s of unrelated things and there doesn't even appear to be a way to search.  I will check the c:\ drive next though.

Answer (score 1):

A list of shutdown reasons can be found in this [MSDN article "System Shutdown Reason Codes"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376885%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The reasons mentioned there are added to the event description after "the following reason: ". This is also the place where you will find user-initiated restarts and their reasons.

As other users already mentioned, you can find these events in the event viewer. Filter for eventid 1074.